# Trouble writing new package for a numbered 'tcolorbox' style with option for 'number within'

Tags: tcolorbox, package-writing, package-options, pgfopts

I am writing a new package to define a numbered box style (using `tcolorbox`) that I use in multiple documents. I want to take the numbering convention of the box as a package option. By default, I want the numbering to be within section: `number within=section,`.

However, with `number within=,`, a global numbering is used by tcolorbox. I want to be able to replicate this when I pass `numbering=,` as the package option, but it exits with an error.

### File `mybox.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mybox}

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

% package options
\pgfkeys{%
    /mybox/.cd,
        numbering/.store in=\mybox@\numbering,
        numbering=section, % 'default' value
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mybox}

% define box style
\newtcolorbox[%
    auto counter,
    number within=\mybox@\numbering,
]{mybox}[1][]{%
    title={\bfseries Box~\thetcbcounter},
    #1
}
```

#### Default package option

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mybox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}
        Hi
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

#### Usage with `numbering=subsection`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbering=subsection]{mybox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}
        Hi
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

#### With `numbering=,` (no value)

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbering=,]{mybox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}
        Hi
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Compile error: `` You can't use `the character .' after \the. H `` at line 7.

Expected output: box with a global numbering

[image]

Comment: Seems to me you default to section or subsection, but not to an empty number box. Maybe you should include a test for that option. Seen that test done often as a `\if` `\else` option.

Comment: Thank you, that is possible, but would require repetitive definitions of `mybox` in each of the branch: all settings except `number within` would be the same. I took this approach wanting to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro you want  to `/.store in` has a non-working name, should be `\mybox@numbering` instead of `\mybox@\numbering`. Also the following expands the `\mybox@numbering` before `tcolorbox` parses its keys.

The following should work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mybox.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mybox}

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

% package options
\pgfkeys{%
    /mybox/.cd,
        numbering/.store in=\mybox@numbering,
        numbering/.default = {}, % if no value is passed use an empty value
        numbering=section, % 'initial' value
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mybox}

% define box style
\expanded{\noexpand\newtcolorbox[%
    auto counter,
    number within=\mybox@numbering,
    ]}{mybox}[1][]{%
    title={\bfseries Box~\thetcbcounter},
    #1
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbering=,]{mybox}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
    \begin{mybox}
        Hi
    \end{mybox}
\section{Two}
    \begin{mybox}
        Hi
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]